# Can't hibernate (+ poor computer literacy)

Tags: hibernate

When I try to hibernate my computer I receive 2 messages and computer turns off:

```
pnp_bus_resume+0x0/0X70 returns -19
PM: Device 00:08 failed to thaw error -19
```

Can something be done?

UPD: Thanks to the @minerz029 the message about free swap has disappeared. But computer still can't hibernate.

Comment: You need to increase your swap space. See here: [How to increase SWAP space in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/178712)

Comment: @minerz029 Thank you for the link and your fast response!

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, 'swap space' is used when your computer decides that you don't need these files right now, but they should be easily accessible (it may seem strange but accessing files from the hard drive is very very slow in computer terms).

I just recently installed Ubuntu and was given the warning that it's highly recommended to reserve some swap space on the hard drive. The post linked by minerz029 has fairly simple instructions for creating a file that's used as swap space. However, if it's reasonable for you to overwrite your existing Ubuntu install, it may be easier to do that and in the process create a partition for use as swap space.