# Allocate free space to Ubuntu partition with 4 primary already existing?

Tags: partitioning

I just made 120 GB of unallocated space from my Windows 8 partition to put into my already existing Ubuntu home (sda7) partition.

The problem is when I try to create new partition from unallocated it says

> **It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions**

All I want to do is put that free space into my Ubuntu (to sda7).

[image]

```
sda2 - Windows 8 drive C
sda3 - Windows 8 drive D
```

Edit: So I run "Try Ubuntu", unmounted all partitions, and resized `/dev/sda4` so unallocated space is not below sda4. But when I try to resize `/dev/sda7` (which I want) it only allows me to resize for 7Gb or so, not all 120Gb I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put that 120 GB free space into  Ubuntu ( `/dev/sda7`) partition,follow the below steps.

- First you had to boot Ubuntu live disk.
- Click on "try ubuntu" option on startup and then open gparted from Dash.Make sure that all your partitions are unmounted.
- Right-click on the `/dev/sda4` partition and then choose Resize/Move option to increase its size with the 120 GB unallocated space by dragging the left arrow to the extreme left.After resizing,apply the changes.
- Now your 120 GB unallocated space will comes inside extended partition and just below to the `/dev/sda7` partition.
- Right-click on the `/dev/sda7` partition and select Resize/Move option,now you can be able to add 120 GB unallocated space to your ext4 partition by dragging the right arrow to the extreme right.

Comment: Thank you! By the way is it possible to do that if I just reboot into Windows 8?

Comment: Boot ubuntu live disk and then do all the above steps,it will works.

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't know Linux partition format, So it can't resize it. As @AvinashRaj, use Ubuntu live CD or USB key.

Comment: Sneetsher, thanks. Anyways I unmounted all partitions in Live ubuntu usb and now unallocated space is below sda4, which is good, but I cannot resize sda7 for some reason. It allows me resize only around 7Gb, and not all 120Gb. Any ideas?

Comment: plz take a screenshot and then post it to imgur.com and then provide the link as comment.

Comment: Here we go: http://i.imgur.com/Fj2yHD2.png

Comment: did you see that your 120 GB unallocated space was at the top of extended partition.How did it goes to the top?

Comment: Because I increased extended partition's (sda4) size as you said in your answer at 3rd step, so it moved below, just like your 4th step says...

Comment: ok anyways you need to move the unallocated space just above to the `sda7` partition so that you can be add the space to your ubuntu sda7 partition for this see [case2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/389067#389067) in my answer.

Comment: But unallocated space is in fact inside the extended partition, you case3 says exactly what I did and then it moved inside extended!

Comment: you can be able to add space to the partition only if the unallocated space present above or below the partition.So see my case2 to get down the unallocated space.

Comment: Now I understand what you are saying! Everything is solved, just strange that is't not possible to allocate to certain partition immediately. Thank you Avinash.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the limit due to upgrade from windows to ubuntu-- where you already used up 4 primary partitions - only remedy is to backup data - re-install and this time use gparted to create required no of partitions/types.

I faced the same problem -- I used the same D: /E: drive from windows 10 installation - but formatted C: drive for ubuntu.