# Will swap space auto-adjust when I upgrade my physical memory?

Tags: memory-usage

When I installed Ubuntu 13.10 I just ran through the default setup. Since then, I have decided to upgrade my physical memory.

My question is, Will Ubuntu auto-adjust the default swap size to match the new memory.

If not, how do I adjust it myself?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/389067#389067

Answer (score 3):

No, it will not change it's size because of upgrading/changing the physical memory.

The swap system in linux is a separate partition type "Linux swap" (82). To change this it would be the easiest way to boot from a [GParted](http://gparted.org/) live system. With this you can decrease the size of your root partition and increase the size of the swap partition. GPArted is very easy to use and self-explanatory.

**But notice**, when you upgraded your systems physical memory (I assume you increased it) it is not neccessary to increase the swap partition. Swap is only needed when your physical memory is full or when your hibernate the system (must be at least as big as your ram size)

Comment: What about `suspend`? Shouldn't `swap` be at least as big as `RAM`?

Comment: That's true for hibernation. Thank it added your suggestion.