# Ubuntu 12.04, why so laggy?

Tags: 12.04

I installed only Ubuntu 12.04 on an old Dell Inspiron 9400 laptop and it ran great... for about a month. Now it seems to force its way through the mainstream tasks. It may be an old laptop but I could use around 5 browser tabs with no problems, no matter which browser I used. It just seems to freeze quite often. When I close everything, there doesn't appear to be much activity (only the system monitor open, but everything is normal). I tried the free -m command and this is what it outputs

```
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
   Mem:          1001        745        255          0         24        366
   -/+ buffers/cache:        355        646
   Swap:         1020          1       1019
```

Any idea why it slows down so much and what should be done, besides trying a fresh install?

--Update--
List of Hardware

```
 description: Portable Computer
    product: MP061 ()
    vendor: Winbond Electronics
    serial: 5T78L2J
    width: 32 bits
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable uuid=44454C4C-5400-1037-8038-B5C04F4C324A   *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0YD479
       vendor: Winbond Electronics
       physical id: 0
       serial: .5T78L2J.CN129616AD3842.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Winbond Electronics
          physical id: 0
          version: A04
          date: 09/29/2006
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU         T5600  @ 1.83GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.15.6
          serial: 0000-06F6-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: Microprocessor
          size: 1333MHz
          capacity: 2130MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 166MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 id=0 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 700
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 701
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             clock: 66MHz (15.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.1
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.2
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 1GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: NT512T64UH8B0FN-37
             vendor: Nanya Technology
             physical id: 0
             serial: 96223A31
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 512MiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: NT512T64UH8B0FN-37
             vendor: Nanya Technology
             physical id: 1
             serial: 1DE87810
             slot: DIMM_B
             size: 512MiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 03
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:efd00000-efefffff ioport:d0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: RV515/M54 [Mobility Radeon X1400]
                vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:efdf0000-efdfffff memory:efe00000-efe1ffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:efffc000-efffffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:40000000-401fffff ioport:40200000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:efc00000-efcfffff ioport:40400000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:18:de:a5:73:66
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.8.0-36-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 ip=192.168.192.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
                resources: irq:45 memory:efcff000-efcfffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:43 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:efa00000-efbfffff ioport:e0000000(size=2097152)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:bf80(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:bf60(size=32)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 ioport:bf40(size=32)
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.3
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 ioport:bf20(size=32)
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:ffa80000-ffa803ff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: e1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: memory:ef900000-ef9fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:15:c5:55:78:a8
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=half latency=64 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
                resources: irq:19 memory:ef9fd800-ef9fdfff
           *-generic:0
                description: SD Host controller
                product: R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.1
                version: 19
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:ef9fd500-ef9fd5ff
           *-generic:1
                description: System peripheral
                product: R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.2
                version: 0a
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm cap_list
                configuration: driver=r592 latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:ef9fd600-ef9fd6ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: xD-Picture Card Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.3
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.3
                version: 05
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm cap_list
                configuration: driver=r852 latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:ef9fd700-ef9fd7ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:bfa0(size=16)
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:10c0(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: TOSHIBA MK1234GS
             vendor: Toshiba
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: AH00
             serial: X6LTT9P8T
             size: 111GiB (120GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=0002ef81
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 0714fe2d-ac7a-4346-9215-28a3f34d140d
                size: 29GiB
                capacity: 29GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2013-11-10 22:07:53 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2013-11-22 14:36:32 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2014-02-28 17:41:20 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 1021MiB
                capacity: 1021MiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 1021MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 09b8-b67c
                size: 81GiB
                capacity: 81GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-11-19 18:09:11 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD writer
             product: DVD+-RW ND-6650A
             vendor: _NEC
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 102C
             serial: [
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc   *-battery
       product: DELL 00
       vendor: GW�
       physical id: 1
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 66000mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.1V
```

Comment: "lag" is subjective and can be due to a number of problems. Coul dbe anything from a faulty wireless driver to a problem with your video card. Please identify your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't have enough swap or memory for the applications to run properly , this hopefully can be improved by increasing the size of your swap space.

There is varying opinion on what the size of the swap should be, but here is one from the [Fedora 64bit docs](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-x86.html#idm219179287040)) *(can't find the Ubuntu one... there was one, I did find it ages ago...)*:

[image: For <2GB, it recommends the swap should be '3 times the amount of RAM' in size.]

So you need to have the swap at least twice the size of the RAM, three times the size if you want to allow for [hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation). So you need to have a swap space with atleast the size of `3000` Megabytes

To actually increase the size of the swap space, you don't have to reinstall, you should be able to find a few answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space).

Also, if you to eventually feel the need to reinstall due to these issues, you might want to use an lighter version of Ubuntu, like [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).