# extending win partition in win7 or shrinking ubuntu while in ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have dual boot win7 and ubuntu 12.04
Is shrinking linux partition with gparted somewhat less risky than extending windows partition in windows?

http://postimg.org/image/5qdgafggt/

I would like to extend win7 C: volume from 40gb to maybe 50gb, which means shrinking ubuntu home partition F:volume from 102 to 92gb.
Is it better to do it in ubuntu?

Dual boot is relatively fresh, i dont have so many data on the disk, but i've installed many programs on windows. But extending ntfs C: partition is not the same as shrinking right? There shouldn't be any problem in my opinion?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, it's better to shrink Ubuntu home partition using Ubuntu Live disk.can you upload the screenshot of gparted?

Comment: Here it is:

http://postimg.org/image/i6n2u6sjt/

So i just need to backup my data on ubuntu? are win programs mostly safe since it's just extending ntfs partition? or my logic is not right :)

Answer (score 0):

- Boot Ubuntu live-disk and click on try Ubuntu option on startup.
- Open gparted from dash.Make sure that all the partitions are unmounted.
- Shrink dev/sda7 partition to get 10 Gb unallocated space.
- Now the unallocated space will comes under `/dev/sda7` partition.Now you have to getout of the unallocated space from the extended partition.To do this,
- Right-click on the `dev/sda3` and select Move/Resize.Now you can be able to reduce it's space.
- Now the free space will comes out of the extended partition.
- Right-click on the `dev/sda3` and select Resize/Move option.Click and move the bar to extreme right, so that the unallocated space will comes just above to the `dev/sda3` partition.
- Now you can be able to resize `/dev/sda2` partition.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/389067/202806) for more details.