# Ubuntu partition resize help

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Here's what my current partition table looks like:

[image: My current partion scheme]
Now, I'd like to increase the size of my Ubuntu partition (/dev/sda8) to, say, 20 GB. But it seems to me there's no way to do that other than deleting everything and starting anew, which makes me scared (don't want to lose all the settings and good stuff).

When I tried to do this via the GParted editor in boot mode, it warned that moving partitions will mess up the bootloader and operating systems and what not, so I didn't do it.

I'm a total noob, so am requesting someone to help me achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: you want 13 GB space from which partition?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/a/389067/202806

Comment: @dotslash Did you able to find solution from [how-to-resize-partitions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)?

Comment: That question is only related to this one in that they are both about manipulating partitions on disk.  That is where the similarity ends, so voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always before doing something like this, make sure you have an up to date backup of any important data ( you *DO* backup your important data right? ), then you can shrink sda5, move sda6, sda7, and sda8 to the left, then that will leave you with free space at the end, which you can expand sda8 into.

Comment: i think no need to get down the free space at the bottom.He can be able to resize it's `/dev/sda8` partition when the free space was just above to the sda8.

Comment: This what I was about to do originally when GParted Live warned me that this might screw up the bootloader. So I ended up asking here. Let me try it and if it works, will accept this as answer. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, The free space wouldn't be in front of sda8, it would be in front of sda6.

Comment: @dotslash, you can ignore that warning.

Comment: I said, after moving sda6 and sda7 partition, the free space will come in front of sda8.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, ahh yes, then in that case gparted will translate your request to expand to the front into move+expand for you.

Comment: @psusi Just did that and all is fine in my Ubuntu Land. Thanks a lot! :D