# Installing Ubuntu with windows 8..free space problem

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have windows 8 and I have disable fast boot and secure boot from the UEFI and from inside Windows 8. I have 3 primary partitions in windows and I did some shrinking on one of them and made a 50 GB free space. I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04 on this , but when I get to the install part, it does not show any free space available at all.

Answer (score 0):

From that freespace, you have to create a separate ext4 partition for Ubuntu.So that the installer will detect your ext4 partition after choosing the something else option during installation.

To create an ext4 partition from the free space, you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk.Then click on try Ubuntu option on startup.

After that, a desktop like screen will appear.Search for Gparted Partition Editor in dash.Gparted allows you to create ext4 partition from the free space(aka unallocated space).

> Does this have anything to do with 3 Primary partitions?

Disk with MSDOS partition table allows 3 primary partitions and an Extended partition.But the disk with GPT allows upto 128 partitions.

If you can't able to create a partition from the free space, it means you have a disk with MSDOS partition table and it already contains 4 partitions(3 primary+1 extended).So you have to move that unallocated space into extended partition.And then create a new one from that space.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/389067/202806) answer will help you to move the unallocated space into the extended partition.