# Increasing size of swap partition

Tags: partitioning, swap

There are other postings on this topic, but because of the importance of getting it right I am posting the exact details of my requirement.

My disk is:

```
/dev/sda
  /dev/sda/sda1 to be mounted as /     has  10GB
  /dev/sda/sda6 to be mounted as /home has 150GB
  /dev/sda/sda5 to be mounted as /swap has   1GB
```

I have 1GB of RAM and think it would be advisable to increase the `/swap` partition to 2GB (tell me if you disagree). There is no unallocated space on the disk although plenty of spare space in /home. Can I increase the `/swap` either when installing Ubuntu 14.04 or with something like Gparted, without damaging the data in `/home`? Obviously I would do a backup first.

Comment: post  gparted screenshot to imgur.com and then provide the uploaded link here.

Comment: Looks different in Gparted: http://imgur.com/3m298TV

Comment: how much do you want for your swap partition and from where(According to the screenshot)?

Comment: See original post. System partition isn't very big so will have to be taken from /home.

Comment: from `/home` partition.

Comment: yes. Is it possible to take space which is allocated to a partition and allocate it to another partition?

Comment: Why don't you simply add a 1G swapfile as in (for example) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04 ? Unless your /home is severely fragmented, the performance hit is quite low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot from Ubuntu live disk and then click on try Ubuntu option on starup.
- Open gparted partition editor from dash.
- After it opened, make sure that all the partitions are unmounted(including swap).So that only you can be able to resize corresponding partition.If the swap partition is already mounted then select Swap off option on right-clicking swap partition to get unmounted.
- Shrink your `/home`(`/dev/sda6`) partition to get 1 GB of free space and add it to your `/dev/sda5` swap partition.

Comment: Thanks, that is clear enough. Sorry to labour the point, but obviously I am concerned about my data - is it safe to take space from a partition with data in and re-allocate it?

Comment: yes, it's safe.Follow my instructions given in the answer correctly.If you have any doubts, feel free to ask me.Please don't do anything wrongly.See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/389067#389067

Comment: I didn't really follow the link as it seems to be talking about unallocated space, but it doesn't matter. The reason I asked is because I have just installed elementaryOS and have had a few problems with it and found there is very little support, I will give it another couple of days and if the help doesn't materialise I will install something else, this is the point at which it would make sense for me to change the partitions. I'll let you know what happens. I will of course take great care with it - it's the scariest job on an OS I think.

Comment: Ok, go on with partitioning. And don't forget to accept my answer if it works.

Comment: I'll have to do a backup first.

Comment: backup most important datas. I resized my partitions many times through gparted without backing up the datas.

Comment: I've used System Monitor several times, with a large spreadsheet and many YouTube videos open, and only about 20% of swap was used, so I have decided that I don't need to increase it. Your help was invaluable though, and I will be confident to use your instructions in the future if I need to.