# Increasing swap memory in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, ram, swap

I want to know if it is possible to increase swap memory in Ubuntu 14.04.
How is it possible?

Another question:

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop (ASUS)...When I'm working with it and open URL pages and doing something else the speed start decreasing and speed quality is not satisfactory...What is the problem?

**NOTE: My swap memory is 6G now and my RAM memory is 4G...**

Comment: Yes, it's possible to increase your swap partition. RAM size or SWAP size may be the problem. If you want to increase your swap partition's size then post the screenshot of gparted.

Comment: Could you possibly tell me how it is possible? Thanks

Comment: This [one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450716/increasing-size-of-swap-partition)?

Comment: when you type "free", how much swap does it say is used?

Comment: see my answer in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/389067#389067 question.

Comment: My laptop is not here right now...Thank you very much for asnwering me...I am going to test after that I would tell you... Thanks

Comment: @ubfan1  result of `free` command is: `Swap:      5858300    5858300`

Comment: So the numbers are in the "total" and "used" columns, with nothing in the "free" column?  If so, yes, you can use more swap,a but better figure out what is using all that memory storage -- I never swap with only 2G of memory.

Comment: No my swap memory is 6G = 5858300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is easier to simple add swap with swap file

Create swapfile. Count is size of swap file

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=5048576
```

format file

```
mkswap /swapfile
```

Turn on swap

```
swapon /swapfile
```

Edit fstab to add swap

```
/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```