# How to resize swap (not just adding it)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, swap, virtualization

I made Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) in my VM and I gave it 350gb of my 1tb HDD space and I did it fixed (not dynamically allocated) and i did it as a VDI and in my settings I set it to read the space as a SSD. I gave it 2 processors with 2000mb which is low so I was going to set up about 20gb of swap and swappiness of 50.

I was going to follow this guide to set up swap:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

This is what I got:

```
oggie7797@oggie7797-VirtualBox:~$ sudo swapon -s
[sudo] password for oggie7797: 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition   2044924 14344   -1
oggie7797@oggie7797-VirtualBox:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2000792    1741236     259556      25060      13084     349624
-/+ buffers/cache:    1378528     622264
Swap:      2044924      14344    2030580
oggie7797@oggie7797-VirtualBox:~$
```

As you can see, it shows that I have swap even though this is a fresh install and all I have done is install Chrome-dev browser. So, now that I have given as much information that I can think to give I hope that someone can help me figure out how to either delete and create a fresh swap of my desired size or just simply edit this mysteriously preexisting swap to a larger size. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/178726/158442

Comment: I'd also include the output of fdisk /dev/sda in order for you to get the appropriate answer.

Comment: I would gparted, but im crazy like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you have access to a gui and can boot the livecd you can just delete the swap (as the system does at every boot if it is not hibernating) and create a new partition of the size you want.