# Upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 and *everything* lags

Tags: upgrade, performance, 14.10

Yesterday, I upgraded my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (2013) from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10. Since then, everything lags, from applications when opened (or 'drawn back in the background' for an overview of all open applications) to password entry on log-on. Even Google Chrome: youtube videos stutter. Also, when typing this, I feel a bit of a lag. Does anybody experience the same? Maybe under different hardware? [I used the standard software updater to update]

Comment: Same issue here on a 2013 Macbook Air. It seems to come and go.

Comment: This might be related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/541222/ubuntu-gnome-14-10-desktop-performance-degraded-when-certain-apps-are-running

Comment: I did find a number of segfaults from the i915 driver on my machine, but I ended up downgrading anyways.

Comment: Can you post the output of `cpupower frequency-info` - you may need to `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic`

Comment: Hi Charles. I obtain `WARNING: cpupower not found for kernel 3.8.0-22` I then installed `linux-tools-3.8.0-22` as recommended by the further output of cpupower, but obtained `E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-3.8.0-22`. Hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

I have a new carbon. I had slow redrawing of windows and other problems, although no particular problem with video. Fixed with: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#SNA_issues

> If you are experience issues with SNA, try using UXA instead, which can be done by creating an X configuration file containing the following:
>
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
>
>
> `Section "Device"
>    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
>    Driver      "intel"
>    Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
> EndSection`

EDIT: DO NOT USE THIS SOLUTION. SNA has been fixed. Upgrade your kernel (at least 4.0 probably) and video card drivers (>=2.99.917 i think) instead.

Comment: Please, take a time and write down the solution here. Thanks

Comment: This solved my graphics lag issues on a Lenovo ThinkCentre M90P (Intel graphics) with Xubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable and allocate enough of a swap partition to be used as virtual memory when your RAM  fills up?

See the source below to increase or create some swap space if you haven't. If it's still a problem then my guess would be it's a driver issue.

See [How to increase swap space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem too back when I had 14.04 though once I reinstalled Ubuntu it worked perfectly. Basically try reinstalling Ubuntu or either try checking out graphics drivers and try install the ones tailored for your graphics instead of using the default Xorg drivers.

Answer (score -2):

I recently updated to 14.10 too.  I'm using a lenovo ideapad and it has worked fine.  To fix your problem I would recommend changing startup applications, lowering swappiness, and other minor speed fixed you can find on google.  If this dose not work I would suggest making a Ubuntu 14.10 bootable USB and completely reinstalling your operating system.  Good luck!