# Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 - desktop performance degraded when certain apps are running

Tags: gnome, graphics, performance

I have upgraded from Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 to 14.10 yesterday using standard Software Updater GUI. The upgrade went smooth, however once upgrade was done I've noticed significant desktop performance degradation only when certain applications are running at the time. Basic desktop operations like switching between workspaces is accompanied by visible lag and stuttering, which is extremely annoying and disruptive in daily workflow.

I've recorded a screencast demonstrating this problem - I've used standard Image Viewer application (ver. 3.12.2) and Google Chrome as example apps causing this issue - which is not to say that these are ONLY applications causing it.

The screencast video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LhKhdgKHiQ

I've googled around this issue and tried several workarounds related to GPU's hw acceleration, yet none of these attempts fixed the problem.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

As suggested in the comment below, I've executed glxinfo to gather additional graphics/acceleration data, however I don't have a clue how to read this: http://pastebin.com/JRuTgQSa

Additionally, I've filed a bug report in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1385764

Comment: This looks like a graphics driver and/or compositor issue. Can you please [perform some diagnostics](/q/14008/175814) and post the results?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've ran glxinfo but I don't have a clue how to read these values, to be honest.. see: http://pastebin.com/JRuTgQSa

Comment: Thanks so far. `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` from after opening a problematic application and closing it again after a while could be helpful. I think it would be beneficial to add or link diagnostic data to your question instead of to the comments.

Comment: It seems that I experienced something similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/540964/upgraded-to-ubuntu-14-10-and-everything-lags See also other comments there, we seem to not be alone on this. Extremely annoying.

Comment: You should try and get a trace https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces/

Answer (score 1):

If you have Integrated Intel graphics, you could try

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

then rebooting. This worked for me on a Dell XPS laptop - everything became smooth again.  Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1385764

If you subsequently have problems with

```
optirun glxgears
```

giving "Can't open secondary"...

Try,

```
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates
```

then

```
 gksudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

Under the section `[bumblebeed]` change the Driver: `Driver=nvidia`

Under `[driver-nvidia]` change references in this section from `nvidia-current` to `nvidia-331-updates`.  That's in the `KernelDriver`, `XorgModulePath` and `LibraryPath`.

Then reboot, and try

```
optirun glxgears
```

Source: http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/solved-nvidia-cant-access-secondary-gpu.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue by switching my gpu acceleration method from 'sna' to 'uxa'. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#SNA_issues

> If you are experience issues with SNA, try using UXA instead, which can be done by creating an X configuration file containing the following:
>
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
>
>
> `Section "Device"
>    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
>    Driver      "intel"
>    Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
> EndSection`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, could you please explain the essential parts from the link in your answer? The internet changes and if the content on the link is changed or removed then your answer will help no one. It is better to explain how to solve the issue directly in AskUbuntu and leave the link as a source.