# Increasing Swap file

Tags: swap

I looked at various Q's all ready asked, but did not see my problem.

I am trying to increase my swap by using GParted Partition Editor as in [How to increase swap space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space)

I try to resize/move, but it says 510mbs. I can't make it any bigger. I have tried to delete it, and so on. It always comes up as 510mb. I have over 20 gigs free on the hdd. So what am I doing wrong, or what did I read wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of gparted to the question.

Comment: Are you using solution 2 or solution 1?  Both are using different kinds of swap.  Are you using a swap file or a swap partition?  (or maybe you're using both, which is a bad idea as you need to follow both solutions) can you provide the output to `sudo swapon --summary` *before* you reboot into the LiveCD?

Comment: This question was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space#178726) .