# Help to resize partition with Gparted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm new with GParted and with linux partition in general..
I followed this answer : [How to increase swap space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/389067#389067)

But my situation is a bit different and "extend left/right" is driving me crazy.. I can't extend /dev/sda1 with unallocated 7.16 GB.

Someone could explain the right actions in the right order ?
Or just tell me that in my case it's not possible..

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Of course you cannot extend it since there is no empty space right beside it. Tell us what exactly your aim is. Then we can help with exact instruction

Comment: There is the swap partition, /dev/sda5, between /dev/sda1 and unallocated space. It needs to be removed before you can extend /dev/sda1.

Comment: yes, you should delete /dev/sda5, then resize /dev/sda1 and then recreate /dev/sda5, as the others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only resize partitions that have unallocated space next to what you want to resize.

So ...

- make the whole of sda2 unallocated by removing swap.
- make sda1 larger minus the size you want to use for swap + a few mbs overhead
- recreate swap partition on sda2

Comment: Ok thanks, it works like a charm ! I was hesitant about removing the linux-swap partition !

My Ubuntu boot as expected and, now, it has 15Go for sda1.