# lshw unclaimed memory and processor core

Tags: ram, memory-usage

How do I claim back  unclaimed memory and processor core. Below is the output of sudo lshw.I put in 2 sticks 4gb each and have 64 bit 16.04 lts system

```
    description: Computer
    product: Aspire 4520
    vendor: Acer, inc.
    version: Not Applicable
    serial: LXAJN0X010907200B52524
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=oem-specific uuid=0061351A-46E0-DB11-9200-00238B3A1A90
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Mono
       vendor: Acer, Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Applicable
       serial: LXAJN0X010907200B52524
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Acer
          physical id: 0
          version: v1.3632
          date: 05/14/2008
          size: 105KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-64
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: New Processor Technology
          slot: Socket M2/S1G1
          size: 2200MHz
          capacity: 2200MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch vmmcall lbrv cpufreq
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 64KiB
             capacity: 64KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory:0
          description: System Memory
          physical id: b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous
             physical id: 0
             slot: S1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR2 [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: S2
```

Comment: Try the `sudo dmidecode -t 16` command. I suspect the computer board supports up to 4GB, and if that's the case, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum supported RAM for that model is 4GB so it won't utilize the second 4GB stick of RAM. Your options are to upgrade the motherboard to one that supports more RAM or obtain a different system that can or live with 4GB and [add swap space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space) as necessary to support your needs.

Sources: http://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-4520-5950-14-1-turion-64-x2-tl-58-2-gb-ram-120-gb-hdd/specs/

Experience

Comment: As you’re a reputation 11 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!