# unknown (not allocated) partition at Ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: 14.04, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, mount

I am installing ubuntu in my laptop. This is my current disk partition.

```
/dev/sdb1 = 170GB primary that install ubuntu
/dev/sdb2 = 140GB logical
/dev/sdb3 = 160GB logical
/dev/sdb4 = 155GB logical
/dev/sdb5 = 3GB swap area
/dev/sdb1 = 15GB unknown (not allocated)
```

I want this `/dev/sdb1 15 GB` unknown (not allocated) to use as swap area with `/dev/sdb3`

This 15 GB is not merged with `/dev/sdb1 primary`.

Comment: why not use 16.04 or 17.04 ?

Comment: `/dev/sdb1` listed twice with different size?! What does “use as swap area with `/dev/sdb3`” mean? Do you want to use it as the only swap partition for the Ubuntu installed to `/dev/sdb3`, or to have two swap partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot Ubuntu from a Live disk and run `Gparted`.

Then unmount all the partitions and add the unknown space to your swap partition.

You can also check [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/389067#389067) if you have any confusion. That link provides in details what I have said.