# 58% of Memory Used, Warning for High MemSwap

Tags: 16.04, ram, swap

Couldn't find anything related to this so I thought I would ask. As you can see in the attached screenshot I have a decent system but I noticed something that I am not sure if I need to be concerned about. The memory usage is holding steady at 58%(ish), but the machine is showing High MemSwap usage.

The machine is running great, nothing is lagging or slowing down. I do have several programs open and running, multiple web browsers and windows, Skype, Terminal, Thunderbird, Spotify etc etc.

Is this high swap usage something I should be worrying about?

Edit: To reiterate the system runs flawlessly, nothing crashes, nothing lags, it's just giving the error/warning about MemSwap.

[image: Memory Snapshot]

Edit: Output from `free --si -h`
[image: Output]

Comment: How big is that swap?  Looks like 200MB.  The system may not use it that much, but when it tries to swap anything into it, you will get that warning.  If you are going to use a swap file, you might want it at 1x RAM or 1.5x RAM which would be somewhere between 8GB ~ 12GB.  Mine is 8GB and no warnings or errors.  Choose what works best for you.

Comment: Glances is showing it at 194M with 580K free. I don't recall setting the Swap size manually though so not sure why it would be that small? Unless it's something else.

Comment: Give or take a few 100K but still looks around 200MB.  [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1005001/edit) your question and include the output of `free --si -h` which should just give you only the memory and swap information.

Comment: You can also check https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space on creating a new or increasing your swap file.

Comment: Yup fixed the issue, I am a derp, thanks for your help

Comment: No worries!  Sometimes a second pair of eyes helps and I'm glad I could help!  =)