# Ubuntu 19.04 freezes after suspend

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, 19.04

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu 19.04. kernel version is 5.0.0-13 generic. I am using it with dual boot alongside Windows. Whenever I suspend or close the lid of the laptop ,the laptop hangs and screen goes blank. The only way is to force shutdown the laptop. I have tried editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and `/etc/default/grub`
but nothing happens.

I have also tried to change boot menu from `AHCI` to `IDE` as was suggested in some posts.

The only difference after changing in `/etc/default/grub` was:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to nouveau.modeset=0
```

Is that the lock screen appears but still in freeze mode.

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend for how to debug the problem for your particular hardware, and how to file the appropriate bug report.

Comment: I have the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Same issue here in a Dell Inspiron 7373, sometimes instead of freeze, the laptop just reboot, and the issue is present also with 18.04

Answer (score 1):

this fixed it for me:
add `blacklist intel_agp` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, reboot and try again

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain what your solution does?

Comment: Tried it but still freezing after suspend. One thing I noticed though is that the time on the lock screen is that of when the laptop was suspended not when i wake the laptop from suspend. This means that the laptop freezes immediately after suspend

Comment: don't forget `update-initramfs -u` after that.

Comment: Tried it. Now even the freezed screen is gone.

Comment: chiwowahh's answer made suspend work again for me again, tks! One remaining issue is that the background after suspend is pitch black with some sprinkled stars, replacing disco dingo.

Comment: This didn't work for me on my older xps 13, unfortunately. Mine has an i5 5200U, fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your swap partition is at least as big as your RAM. If it isn't your system might try to dump your memory state into a too small volume when suspending. This will lead to a crash. Defining a too small swap-space might have happened when you configured your dual-boot system.

Comment: This answer directed me the solution. A note: we have both swap file and partition.

By default, apparently, ubuntu does not create a swap partition, but have a swap file. Currently (20.04), 2GB appears to be the default. It should suffice for some users, but not for highly-RAM demanding uses, or if currently the memory size is not so big... (at least as big as RAM make sense considering the content in the memory will be saved in Swap memory for hibernation).
How to increase the allocation in the swap file: https://askubuntu.com/a/1177939/1188532 or https://askubuntu.com/a/1264577/1188532