# Increase swap in 20.04

Tags: partitioning, swap, hibernate

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm trying to create a hibernate command. I'm following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259645/1103141).

Step 2 says

> Then check whether the swap memory you allocated is more than or at least equal to the Physical memory(RAM).

I did that, and my `/swapfile` is 2 GB. I have 16 GB RAM, so I need to increase the size of that swap file. How do I do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-increase-swap-space-on-linux-ubuntu)?

Comment: There's also this one, relating to increasing swap under LVM and with encrypted drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031275/increase-swap-in-ubuntu-18-04-under-lvm-and-encrypted-file-system

Comment: The answers below are great if your swap is a file. What if it's a partition?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In sleep mode, the content of ram is kept as it is, and the computer works on a very low power mode, so as to keep the ram content intact (as ram will lose the data if power supply is cut to it). But in hibernation, the ram content is stored in the swap space, so power can be completely cut off. Hence it is recommended to have swap size as large as the ram size.

1. First, find the swap file, disable and delete it

   ```
    swapon --show
    NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
    /swapfile file   2G   0B   -2

    sudo swapoff /swapfile  
    sudo rm  /swapfile
   ```
2. Create new swap space of size 16 GB (16 * 1024 = 16384). `bs` is the block size. Basically bs * count = bytes to be allocated (in this case 16 GB). Here bs = 1M (M stands for mega, so we are assigning 1MB block size) and we are allocating 16384 * 1MB (=16GB) to swap.

   ```
    sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=16384
   ```
3. Give it the read/write permission for root

   ```
    sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
   ```
4. Format it to swap

   ```
    sudo mkswap /swapfile
   ```
5. Turn on swap again

   ```
    sudo swapon /swapfile
   ```
6. Now reboot the PC for the above changes to take place.

Comment: There is no need to delete the file or use `dd`. It is much faster and easier to `fallocate`. Why would you write zeros there?

Comment: @Pilot6 Sure even that works. I remember that I used the above commands, hence I wrote that. I am sure that the OP owner just needs to get the work done, rather than quickly.

Comment: This was quite helpful... Thanks

Comment: Thanks Abhay Patil. Just a note: I did not need to reboot on Ubuntu 20.04 and you can put the swapfile where you want (doesn't need to be in the root folder/drive).

Comment: @LouisGagnon noted the location thing, but I remember I had to restart before the changes took place. Well anyways better to be on the safer side.

Comment: @LouisGagnon but it's better to put it in the root, because if you put it, say, into /home/user, you might accidentally delete it.

Comment: @Programmer if the user deletes the swap file, does that mean swap will be turned off and the system will be left with no swap space?

Comment: @AbhayPatil yes - if it wouldn't mean this, there would be not need to create the SWAP file by hand - the system would create it at the next reboot by itself. Deleting the Swap file can have bad consequences - if any unsaved documents were opened, the changes you made will be lost; also this can lead to a system crash. At next reboot, everything will be normal again - except for that your RAM gets full quicker !

Comment: Thank you, There is no need to reboot

Comment: @Pilot6 don't think anyone should look for an answer that is done in 1 sec instead of 1 min when you have to do it only ONCE and 1 min answer is already there.

It would be much more valuable if you posted an answer along with that comment

Comment: @Programmer It is bad advice to put it on the root. My ubuntu stopped booting and after boot, it was killing the terminal automatically on typing anything. It sent an internal error. Also adding 16 GB is generally not recommended just as much as RAM.

Answer (score 15):

Below steps worked for me with `fallocate` approach

1. Check for the Swap Information

> `sudo swapon --show`

Output will be something like below,

```
NAME      TYPE   SIZE   USED   PRIO
/swapfile file    2G     0G    -2
```

2. Deactivate the swap space

> `sudo swapoff /swapfile`

3. Use `fallocate` to instantly creates a file with the specified size.

> `sudo fallocate -l 16G /swapfile`

4. Set the swap space

> `sudo mkswap /swapfile`

5. Activate the swap space

> `sudo swapon /swapfile`

6. Now check for the Swap Information

> `sudo swapon --show`

Now the output will be something like below,

```
NAME      TYPE   SIZE   USED   PRIO
/swapfile file   16G     0B    -2
```

Cheers!

Comment: If the second steps failes (sudo swapoff /swapfile) with "Killed" error message to stop swap you may need to first stop applications/services which consume large amounts of memory. You can identify them using top command or recent OOM by running     grep /var/log/kern.log* -ie 'Out of memory'

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su -
swapoff /swapfile  
rm  /swapfile
\# 32k -> 32GB swap size
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=32K
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
Ctrl+D
```