# Ubuntu 20.04.03: computer freezes randomly in rare circumstances

Tags: 20.04, hardware, freeze, crash

Five days ago I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my computer. As the title says, from time to time the computer would freeze completely, and I have no chance of giving any input to the machine since mouse and keyboard do not work. It doesn't happen regularly, but when it does I'm forced to turn off the computer using the power button.
This is my hardware configuration

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Six-Core Processor
GPU: AMD Radeon RX580X
MOBO: MSI B450 Tomahawk Max
RAM: 4GBx2 Crucial Ballistix Sport (ddr4, 2400 MHz)
```

Running the command free -h this is the output

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem:          7.8Gi       2.4Gi       3.6Gi        66Mi       1.7Gi       5.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: If you use a lot of browser tabs or Electron-based applications, then that 2GB swap is simply insufficient. [You may want to increase it to 16GB](https://askubuntu.com/a/1264577/1222991) or so and see if this reduces the problem 

Comment: Thank you, I followed your advice. I'll keep an eye on it to see if the problem disappears

Comment: @matigo Here I am again. Following the advice given I have increased the Swap space. The system froze again a few minutes ago, the only difference was that I was able to move the cursor, but the system was not responding. I couldn't open the terminal or restart the machine. Once again, I had to turn off the computer manually