# Increase swap space

Tags: swap

I have a ubuntu 16.04 and installed gparted on it and I wonder how I can increase the swap space in my case shown in the below screenshot?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase swap space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space)

Comment: @mikewhatever  I checked that but as shown in the answer my case is not like any of them as my unallocated space is only 5.63MB https://askubuntu.com/a/389067/304905

Comment: Well then, why not create more unallocated space by shrinking one of the partitions?

Comment: @mikewhatever could you advise me how?

Comment: There are many good howtos, all you need to do is search. Here is [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions/18525#18525).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

Using swap on SSDs/NVME drives is not recommended, but here's what you can do if you really want more swap space available on your system:

```
# Replace "n" and /path... accordingly
sudo fallocate -l nG /path/to/swapfile
sudo chmod 0600 /path/to/swapfile
sudo mkswap /path/to/swapfile
sudo swapon /path/to/swapfile
sudo echo '/path/to/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```