# 18.04: How to decrease the swap partition to increase the root partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, swap

I want to resize the swap partition which is approximately 15GB to like 8-9 GB so I can increase the size of my root partition.
I am not even sure if that is possible but I need to install some software and haven't been able to due to lack of space.
Here is a screenshot :

[image: Gparted]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase swap space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space)  Swap partitions are generally passe; swap files run just as fast, and are much easier to manage. See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq for sizing recommendations.

Comment: I am not exactly sure if it does, I can create a swap file but what about my swap partition? That was my question, how do I take 5-7 GB out of it to make it unallocated or just how to get rid of it so I can move on to a swap file.

Comment: LIttle key icons show mounted partitions. You cannot edit mounted partition, so need to use Ubuntu live installer's gparted or a gparted live flash drive to edit. You probably only need 2 or 4GB of swap. The only time larger swap is needed, is if you hibernate, and hibernation is not recommended.

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and run _sudo swapoff_ (ref. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/swapon.8.html ) then the 'key' icon will not appear in gparted when you launch it. Gparted will then allow you to select the internal drive of your PC at upper right (where your picture shows /dev/sda), select the swap partition, select to delete it, and click on the green checkmark to commit the change. Then you can expand /dev/sda5 into its space)/

Comment: Okay, that is much clearer now, thank you so much for your repsonses, I will try it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Would like to suggest that you think of getting an external drive some time in the future.  You would be able to place your data on it, and not worry about running out of space.

Comment: Tell me how much RAM you have, so I can recommend the proper procedure. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.