# Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process ... system freezes

Tags: freeze

Ubuntu 20.04 freezes and message on remote console is as attached.
Did ILOM hard reset to reboot.
Anyone know how to identify the process that caused the oom and why would Ubuntu freeze?

[image: Console]

Comment: You might be in a better position to know this than any of us. The error is explicitly referring to an application that has exceeded the `cgroup` restriction, and those restrictions are created by system admins, not anyone else. [The documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man7/cgroups.7.html) may be able to help you with this one 

Answer (score 1):

The process, that triggered the OOM, is `node`. As you can see behind the process id `1908036`. I is hard to guess, what is going on in you system, but from the `cgroup out of memory` I assume, that there are some containers running node-js.

Start by [increasing the swap space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space) of your system and monitor memory consumption while it is running. If the memory consumption is high than your physical available memory, you should consider using a system with more memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was not aware that node meant node-js.  It is Kubernetes so swap is disabled.  I will have a look around the logs for node-js pod/containers.  Ultimately I want to find the container/process that caused this so it can be fixed.

Comment: You need to monitor the memory before it happens. When the OOM killer hits, he kills the first process how is requesting more memory. So the killed process might not be the cause of the high memory load.