# Ubuntu is very slow, due to these processes or other issues?

Tags: process, top

```
TIME+ COMMAND
------------------
73:39.09 gnome-shell                             
6:39.58 kswapd0                                 
7:20.54 kcompactd0                              
46:26.92 Xorg                                    
2579449 roadrov+
17:18.61 chrome
```

My laptop is very slow these days and almost every time I type "top" I can see these processes in it. All have extremely high TIME+, seems stuck.

Outputs from `free -h`:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.3Gi       4.7Gi       352Mi       2.0Gi       2.3Gi       344Mi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B
```

A few days before I tried to increase my swap size to 8GB using [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/1177939#1177939), all steps seemed successful, untill the last step failed as it prompted `swapon: /swapfile: skipping - it appears to have holes`. This is, I guess, the reason of 0 swap size.

How slow my OS is? -- I only have Chrome, Text Editor, Calendar open, and Chrome have 4 tabs, when I highlight and rightclick on something then click on `search for xxx in Google`, there is a chance that my whole OS freezes, can't even move cursor. After a few seconds everything will be okay, no app would be force quitted by `systemd-oomd`, which used to happen a lot to me before attempting modifying swap size.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @muru Hi, it says that I need >=10 reputation to post image as image

Comment: Yes, that's one more reason why you should post it as ***text***.

Comment: The presence of `kswapd0` suggests that you may be low on RAM and your system is swapping memory pages to disk, a common cause of sluggish desktop behavior. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `free -h`

Comment: @user535733 Hi I've added it and a lot other details in the question

Comment: You added that your swap is broken and unusable, and that you have a teeny 0.35G RAM available to use. To me, that suggests that your problem is *still* RAM. The immediate solution is to open fewer Chrome tabs (web browsers are notoriously RAM-hungry). The later-today solution is to fix your swap.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks. I will try to solve my RAM & swap problems

Comment: @WillowLu fix your swapfile ... before doing anything else. If the system says that the swapfile "has holes" you didn't follow the guide correctly.

Comment: You did not mentioned about your hardware. Are you using SSD or HDD, and how many of them. What kind of CPU do you have?

Comment: @SorenA I've fixed Swap. Thanks

Comment: @FedKad SSD, and 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz. But I've creaed the swap partition successfully, and i think the system won't be as slow as before