# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS - Hibernate does not work with certain programs open

Tags: 22.04, hibernate

Linux newbie here! I recently installed `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` on my system.

Now I'm aware that `hibernate` is not enabled by default, so I followed [these steps](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html#) to enable the `hibernate` option. Some answers on this site also suggested increasing the swap file size, so I [increased](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space/389067#389067) it to `15.0 GB`. My system has `8.0 GB` of `RAM`

### **The Situation:**

After the above steps, **normally I'm able to hibernate if I have only a few applications running**, like in the screenshot below (I use Portrait orientation):

[image: Screenshot]

### **The Issue:**

My issue is that, if I have resource intensive programs running, eg. `Visual Studio Code`, `Webstorm IDE` or even `Sublime Text`, then upon hibernation, **all that happens is that the screen goes off for a few seconds and shows me back the login screen**. In essence, it just turns back on instead of going into hibernate. When I login, the applications are still running; its almost as if I just locked my screen and logged in again.

So every time I need to hibernate, I have to close these programs and then hibernate, which really defeats the purpose of hibernating in the first place.

Could anyone suggest a solution / areas of investigation?