# Mouse misbehaving in lubuntu while it was working fine in windows 7

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, dell

My Dell N-5030 PC is encountering issues with the mouse in Lubuntu, despite its smooth functionality on Windows 7. I've already attempted driver updates through the terminal using commands like "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade." However, the problem persists. I've also tried different USB ports and restarted the computer, yet the mouse misbehavior persists. I'd appreciate guidance on adjusting Lubuntu's mouse settings to ensure they align with my preferences.

Comment: You've not provided any release details; so I'll assume the latest *stable* release which is Lubuntu 23.10; you can look at the manual for operational clues, eg. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html  (that URL is for 23.10; if you're using a different release you can adjust URL); if using a hypervisor there are more details that maybe useful in *Tips & Tricks* too.  Your *kernel stack* choice is set by your installation media; for older & newer hardware this matters as adjusting kernel stack can help (ie. changing kernel changes kernel modules aka *drivers*)

Comment: i was installed 22.04 its working great but mouse misbehaving stucking etc etc plz help i m not so techy ):

Comment: sometimes its working like now but suddenly it fu$%ed up ):

Comment: This is a Q&A site & not a forum, additional details such as 22.04 should be added to your question (*comments are from readers to OP or Original Poster & get removed once dealt with*). Change the word *stable* in my URL to *lts* to read the 22.04 manual page.  I'd first increase swap file size, as the default size maybe to small for your *unstated* RAM size, which can result in what appear like *system freezes* if your machine lacks RAM. Lubuntu's discourse is currently *down* so I'll provide a link on this site https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space

Comment: ram is around 4 gb

Comment: if i cant ask question here plz suggest me that forum

Comment: You can ask your question here, but please use the site as a Q&A site and not a forum. Answers will be to your question (*which doesn't mention a release*) with comments being only *comments* about the question itself.  4GB is reasonable RAM for many tasks, but limited if you're using a web browser. For Swap FAQ refer https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-faq/2591  and the Lubuntu swap page I wanted to provide before is https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-create-a-swapfile-in-lubuntu-20-04-20-10/1959 (Lubuntu discourse is back up).

Comment: Lubuntu 22.04 LTS has two kernel stack options (*selected by ISO used to install*), 22.04 & 22.04.1 used GA kernel stack (5.15) and 22.04.2 & later media (inc. 22.04.3) use HWE which is currently 6.2 when fully upgraded (was 5.19 at 22.04.2, will be 6.5 at 22.04.4). Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for clues, but some hardware (esp. older) does perform better with an older stack (ie. 5.15 kernel; with its kernel modules which are commonly called *drivers*), but I don't think that is your issue. On limited RAM (<6GB RAM) swap size is very important.

Comment: Also asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/mouse-misbehaving-in-lubuntu-while-it-was-working-fine-in-windows-7/4701

Comment: so its happening because of swap? but how to fix it ? i m not so techy i can use terminal though which i learned yet

Comment: with help of youtube i increase swap file to 3 gb i have around 5 gb total ram so all done ? plz check in this image- https://ibb.co/S6Kg58C

Comment: 5880 mb ram total*